# L1 distance between Dirichlet distributions

Tags: mathematical-statistics, dirichlet-distribution

Given two Dirichlet distributions $\mu_{\alpha},\mu_{\beta}$ on the k-simplex, with parameters 
$\alpha = (\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k)$ and $\beta = (\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_k)$, is there an expression for the $L_1$ distance between $\mu_{\alpha},\mu_{\beta}$ in terms of $\alpha,\beta$?

If there is no tractable expression, how to approximate the distance by sampling?

Here $\|\mu_{\alpha}-\mu_{\beta}\|_1 = \int |f_{\alpha}(x) - f_{\beta}(x)| dx$, where $f_{\alpha},f_{\beta}$ are the densities and $dx$ is the Lebesgue measure on the simplex.

Related distance measures would also be of interest, such as if $dx$ is replaced by $f_{\alpha}dx$ for instance. Or perhaps even the transportation distance between $\mu_{\alpha},\mu_{\beta}$, where the simplex is taken with *it's*  $L_1$ distance.

Comment: I don't have an explicit answer to your question. I would suggest reviewing David Blei's fairly authoritative video tutorial, specifically the sections devoted to discussing the Dirichlet as he probably addresses it ... http://videolectures.net/mlss09uk_blei_tm/

Comment: Looking at the Kullback-Leibler divergence may be of interest in this case because $\log( f_{\alpha}(x)/ f_{\beta}(x) )$ would have a nice form.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any closed-form expression for the TV distance between two Dirichlets, though you might be able to work something out. To approximate it by sampling, you could use the fact that
$$\int \left|f_\alpha - f_\beta\right| = \int f_\alpha \left|1 - f_\beta/f_\alpha\right| = \mathbb{E}_{X\sim f_\alpha}|1-f_\beta(X)/f_\alpha(X)|.$$